# Trigger Azure Function App to create a container whenever an image is added in another container

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-functions

**Current Scenario:**

We have created an azure function which will generate thumbnail of each image added to a container named **testcontainer** and will save them to another container named **thumbnail-testcontainer**. Problem is, we have to manually create *thumbnail-testcontainer*. We want this thumbnail container creation process to be automated(using azure function), as the number of containers in azure storage account is more.

Can this container creation step be automated using azure functions which are executed via triggers?

We have taken reference from page https://www.michaelcrump.net/azure-tips-and-tricks75/ but didn't get much help.

Comment: you can add code to your function to create the container when you need a new one

Comment: Hi Manoj, any progress? If my solution doesn't meet your requirement, you could offer more details. Or you can accept it to close your question.

Comment: Hi Jerry, Will try out the output binding option suggested and will update you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [output binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#output---c-example), we don't need to manually create container which is used to save output. Once we specify a container in output binding path, function will automatically create it if it doesn't exist.

```
[FunctionName("FunctionTest")]
public static void Run(
    [BlobTrigger("one/{name}")]Stream myBlob, 
    [Blob("another/{name}", FileAccess.Write)]Stream anotherBlob,
    string name, TraceWriter log)
{
    myBlob.CopyTo(anotherBlob);
    log.Info($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
}
```